# Making a Linked List in Java

Tags: java, exception, data-structures

I am adding elements in a Linked List via scanning the elements one by one using a for loop, but at the end there is a 0 coming while printing the list. The last node is pointing to null but still the list is having one element that is 0. I am providing my source code below and then inputs

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.out;
class Node{
    int data;
    Node next;
    Node(){
       this.next=null; 
          }
    Node(int data){
        this.data=data;
        this.next=null;
          }
}
public class MyClass{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Node head=new Node();
        Node temp=head;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size=sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=1;i<=size;i++){
            temp.data=sc.nextInt();
            temp.next=new Node();
            temp=temp.next;
        }
        temp=null;
        while(head!=null){
            out.print(head.data+" ");
            head=head.next;
        }
    }
  }
```

Inputs:
5 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: And your question is what?

Comment: Your code creates `size + 1` nodes due to `Node head=new Node();` before the loop and `temp.next=new Node();` inside the loop; but only `size` of them receive a value from the user input. So one of the nodes still has a default value of 0 for `data`.

Comment: Actually i am asking that how to stop 0 while printing the elements as a new Node is created which i am not able to stop from creating . I need a direct measure to stop this creation without adding some extra code.

Answer (score 0):

The `next` pointer in the last node of a linked list should be null to denote that it is the last node.

In your case, you are keeping it 'not null'. In your `for` loop, just don't instantiate the `next` pointer if it is the last element you are reading.

```
    for(int i=1;i<=size;i++){
        temp.data=sc.nextInt();
        if(i != size) {
           temp.next=new Node();
           temp=temp.next;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the head-node outside of the loop and a new node within it.
You therefore get 1 extra node.

You might try the following:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Node head=null;
    Node last=null;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int size=sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=1;i<=size;i++){
        if (head == null){
            head = new Node();
            last = head;
        } else {
            last.next = new Node();
            last = last.next();
        }
        last.data=sc.nextInt();
    }
    while(head!=null){
        out.print(head.data+" ");
        head=head.next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that even though you are setting temp=null after you exit your loop, you still have one extra unassigned node.

The simplest fix is to remove the '=' sign in your for loop so that you exit the loop after your last node and then assign your final value, like this:

```
    for(int i=1;i<size;i++){
        temp.data=sc.nextInt();
        temp.next=new Node();
        temp=temp.next;
    }
    temp.data=sc.nextInt();
```